# приложение на kivy и telethon

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, telethon

Начал изучать kivy и для тренировки решил написать простой интерфейс для парсера тг каналов с помощью telethon. Проблема в том, что, когда я запускаю скрипт телетона нажатием на кнопку интерфейса:

```
client.loop.run_until_complete(main(*args))
```

Он забирает управление у интерпретатора и киви приложение просто зависает. Что вообще нужно знать чтобы это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте бота через threading.Thread.

Пример.

```py
threading.Thread(target=lambda: client.loop.run_until_complete(main(*args)))
```